# rendered partial is not able to call javascripts

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have partial which contains messeges list.

when i click on message,

- that message got displayed
- also ajax is updating value of read to true
- rendering partial from update.js.(so user can see unread msg. in bold)

so for first instance it works well but not for second instance.
So i figure it out that my partial doesn't get the script at second time.
Any idea why it is happening?

Code details:
message.js

```
  $(".message_inbox_link").bind('click', function(){
    message_id = $(this).data('messageid');
      $.ajax({
        url: '/private_messages/'+message_id,
        type: 'PUT',
      });
  });
```

controller.rb

```
 def update
    @private_messages = current_user.private_messages.inbox.order('created_at DESC')
    @private_message = PrivateMessage.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      @private_message.update_attribute(:unread, false)
      format.js 
   end
 end
```

update.js

```
$("#inbox").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "inbox") ) %>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in slight in jquery makes it working. but don't know why?

In first case my jquery like this(not worked for second iteration)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".message_inbox_link").bind('click', function(){
    message_id = $(this).data('messageid');
      $.ajax({
        url: '/private_messages/'+message_id,
        type: 'PUT',
      });
  });
});
```

Here is the code which is working

```
$(document).on("click", ".message_inbox_link", function () {
    message_id = $(this).data('messageid');
      $.ajax({
        url: '/private_messages/'+message_id,
        type: 'PUT',
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you're using Ruby, but I've had the same issue after partial page postback in ASP.NET...

For whatever reason you need to re-init your javascript after the partial postback. Here is a detailed explanation on my blog that will hopefully help... http://www.raleighflash.com/article/20

Good luck!